# jQuery event handler fires twice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and have some links that when clicked show a modal. I bind an "on" event handler to "show.bs.modal". When the modal shows I get a data attr value from the button that was clicked. There are several buttons that trigger the same modal, but each button has a different data value assigned to it. When a second button is clicked it runs the event handler twice, once for the first time it was clicked and another time for the second. Here is the code:

```
<a href="#" data-ucid="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" class="delete"><img src="/resources/images/delete.png" class="delete-icon" />
```

```
$('#delete-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var ucId = button.data('ucid');
        var modal = $(this);

        modal.find('.modal-footer .btn-primary').click(function(event) {
            $('#delete-modal').find('.btn-primary').find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-refresh').toggleClass('spinning');
            deleteConnection(ucId);
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost always a bad practice to assign event listeners inside other event handlers

A quick fix for your code would be to use `off('click')` before assigning a new listener

```
modal.find('.modal-footer .btn-primary').off('click').click(function(event) {
```

A better approach would be to use the button event to store data on the modal element and separate the event listeners completely

```
$('#delete-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $(this).data('ucid', $(event.relatedTarget).data('ucid') );
});

$('#delete-modal .modal-footer .btn-primary').click(function(event) {    
    var ucid = $('#delete-modal').data('ucid');
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-refresh').toggleClass('spinning');
     deleteConnection(ucId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the modal footer, it's click event will fire. This will bubble up to the modal and its event will fire also.

If you just want one event to fire, add `e.oreventDefault()` at the end of the modal footer click callback.

Comment: I added event.preventDefault(); but it did not fix the issue. Event handler still fires twice.